# After enable Pro Guard Jackson parser does not work

Tags: java, android, jackson, proguard, retrofit2

I use *Retrofit 2.1.0* with *Jackson 2.8.6* parser.
But if Pro Guard is enable it does not work.

**Exeption in log:**

```
   D/EXAMPLE_PROJ: Class com.example.network.d.b.a.m$a has no default (no arg) constructor 
at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@1c1aab47; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Versions lib in My gradle:

```
dependencies {
    def supportLibraryVersion = "25.3.1"
    def retrofitVersion = "2.1.0"
    def playService = '10.2.0'
    def jacksonVersion = "2.8.6"
```

My pro guard rules for retrofit and jackson:

```
# Retrofit2
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

# Jackson
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
 -dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
 public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }

-keepclassmembers class * {
     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator *;
     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty *;
}
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

I will be glad of any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning Out Solution is very simple in this case. The problem is Proguard deleting my empty constructors in network classes.

1) So, i added this to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep public class com.example.network.**
```

2) Also added @Keep anotation under default empty constructor:

```
@Keep
public MyClass (){
//do not delete
}
```